# Error when overwriting value in unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

Why do I get the error message

```
 error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘unsigned char’ [-fpermissive]
```

if I try to overwrite a certain value in an array of data type **unsigned char**?

The data type I want to overwrite the value is also a **unsigend char**.

Comment: show code that causes that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you use

```
your_array[index] = "C";
```

instead of

```
your_array[index] = 'C';
```

?

Anyway you should put some code on your post to show us where is the error.